# show list items based on who is viewing the list

Tags: list

I'm using SharePoint 2007, and am trying to see if it's possible to filter a list based on who is viewing it?

**Example:** Say, if a user is part of a group could we have the list only show items that are associated with his group? If someone is part of the sir group and the responding system in the list is sir I would want to show that item as well as any other rows that have responding system as sir.

If this can't be done with the list itself could a content query web part work based on the audience?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How many documents are we talking about?**

*I'm not convinced your issue here is so much the capabilities of SP 2007, but more about how your lists/libraries are being designed.*

If permissions are important for your target audience, I would suggest taking another look at how you are separating your content out. **Ask yourself:** *"What am I as a designer, and the user as a stakeholder, getting from keeping all these files in one, or two libraries?"*

**Example:** It might make more sense to give each working group its own document library, and set permissions on the library itself.

Stuffing a bunch of files into one giant library, and then asking "hey, how do I separate this out?" will probably come bite you in bum later down the road when the library grows to an unmanageable size. Building out web-parts should be a last-resort solution! This seems to be a *design problem*.

**Possible Solution:**
For a small quantity of documents, I might assign a specific set of permissions to the documents and/or folders in the list. But this probably isn't the best solution.

Remember that 2007 is for all intensive purposes, 2 major releases behind  - in 2007, I don't think you can assign permissions to specific list views. Someone else might be able to chime in on a technical solution.

Comment: It is only one list that isn't that big, there are 10 different people I would want to want to have a custom view of the list tailored to what they need to see done. I'm just wondering if that is possible to create one view that automatically filters the list data based on who they are instead of creating a bunch of different views. I couldn't create different lists for all of them because they edit the status' and comments of items in the list so it needs to stay updated in one place.

Comment: This is not possible as you describe, to the best of my knowledge. One possible solution might be to create a list column called "department" or whatever, and then have a view group the list content by that column, so that each "topic" is logically separated. List views can not reach into SharePoint programmatically.